# Run custom code against a Wire-Mock request

Tags: api, wiremock

Does **WireMock** allow us to run some arbitrary code against a certain request?

So for example, if an API mock exposes a POST endpoint to add a new item and another GET endpoint to fetch all items that have been added so far. So we could keep a collection on the **WireMock** side and add items to it upon POST and return all items in the collections upon GET.

How would we achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. In case it helps anyone, you can use `WithCallback()` function of `Response` object (and not `WireMockServer` object where I was searching) to call an arbitrary function before returning response to the client. Looks like this:

```
Server.Given(Request.Create().WithPath("/entries/get").UsingGet())
  .RespondWith(Response.Create()
      .WithHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
      .WithCallback(req => {
        //do whatever function you want to call here
        return new ResponseMessage
        {
          BodyData = new BodyData() { BodyAsJson = DATA_OBJECT_TO_RETURN }
        };
       })
      .WithStatusCode(200));
```